# How to integrate crosswalk into the existing ionic objective c project

Tags: ios, objective-c, ionic-framework, crosswalk

All the examples of the crosswalk for the iOS are shown in swift language. I have a project which is working and developed with the help of ionic and objective c. I would like to know who to integrate crosswalk in my project. Also, how can I differentiate if my plugin is integrated or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic does it for you. Just run
`ionic browser add crosswalk` and recompile your app.

More information here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/browsers.html

Comment: as far as I know, Crosswalk is supported only for Android by Ionic, or maybe  there has been some improvement on iOS? (how) did you get it to work, and how did you verify the ios build really used crosswalk?

Comment: Webkit was developed by cordova for iOS - this is basically the main thing you should care about in most cases. Check https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/ios.html